# How to set XML parser's Decimal point character?

Tags: xml, c++builder, decimal-point, firemonkey-fm3, c++builder-xe5

I'm reading attribute fields in an XML document where the decimal point always is `'.'` and the computer local may differ from this (in my own case it is `','`).

I tried to set the global `FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator` to `'.'` but it has no effect on the XML parser. This is a very compressed version of the problem.

```
_di_IXMLDocument Document;
_di_IXMLNode     Node;
float            Value;

Document = LoadXMLDocument("Test.xml");
Node = Document->DocumentElement;
FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator = '.';
Value = Node->GetAttribute("scale");
```

Assume this XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myroot scale="1.234">
</myroot>
```

After reading the attribute scale I always get the result striped on the '.' character resulting in Value = 1234 instead of 1.234.

The number of decimals are not constant, they can be 1 or 4 or anything in between. This also goes for the whole part, so dividing by 100 or 1000 will not solve the problem.

I would preferable have the OLEVariant to accept the `'.'` as a decimal point (my local is `','`).

I had a look at `SetLocalInfo()` but this will set the format for ***ALL*** applications. The `getlocale()` function manipulates the current thread but I have not found a way to explicitly specify the character to use. It seems like it is only possible to select a code page or localization, as in a country.

**EDIT**
I tried to use `setlocal()` and select `English-US` as localization. Even if US are using `'.'` as the decimal separator, the XML Parsers seems to ignore this.

If I manually change the `'.'` to a `','` in the XML file, it works fine. But the XML file is a third party file, which I have no control of. So I really need to read it as it is  with a `'.'` decimal separator

Comment: (This isn't a standard-XML question, it's specifically Microsoft and not portable. So my answer wasn't directly applicable, and I'll refer you to Microsoft.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-known problem with the way the `IXMLNode.NodeValue` property handles floating-point numbers.  It has nothing to do with the underlying XML engine (MSXML, etc).

The `NodeValue` property getter returns an `OleVariant` that contains the attribute value as a `String`, not as a `float`.  You are then assigning that `OleVariant` to a `float`.  The RTL performs a conversion using OS locale settings, not RTL locate settings, which is why `FormatSettings` has no effect.

The `NodeValue` property setter receives an `OleVariant` as input.  Passing a `float` directly to it performs a conversion to a `String` when inserting the value into the XML DOM, and that conversion is also not tied to `FormatSettings`.

`NodeValue` is locale-sensitive, but XML is not.   The XML standard specifically outlines exactly how floating-point numbers must be formatted, which `IXMLNode` does not take into account.  So you will have to read/write floating-point values as `String` values so that you can handle conversions yourself, eg:

```
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
fmt.DecimalSeparator = '.';
fmt.ThousandSeparator = 0;
Value = StrToFloat(Node->Attributes["scale"], fmt);
```

```
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
fmt.DecimalSeparator = '.';
fmt.ThousandSeparator = 0;
Node->Attributes["scale"] = FloatToStr(Value, fmt);
```

Comment: Thank you for the deep explanation. I ended up with a string conversion similar to your suggestion. You confirmed that it wasn't me that failed ;)